# Webpack to export a CLI environment variable to window object

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is there a way to expose an environment variable to the window object using Webpack?

For example, doing `REALM=stage npm run start` I want webpack to read `REALM` and provide it as `window.__realm` so my React app can read it from the `window` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DefinePlugin, documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

In webpack config you need to use plugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({FOO: '123'})
```

In code you need assign to variable:

```
window.FOO = process.env.FOO;
```

When webpack will compile code, it will replace process.env.FOO with '123';
So after compilation you will get:

```
window.FOO = '123';
```

Comment: I tried `new webpack.DefinePlugin({FOO: '123'})` but `window.FOO` does not exist in my browser

Comment: you need to assign like this: window.FOO = process.env.FOO and webpack will process it with DefinePlugin.

Comment: I also tried `new webpack.DefinePlugin({'window.FOO': '123'})` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `libraryTarget` in your `output` config object:

```
output: {
    library: "__realm",
    libraryTarget: "window"
}
```

And access it with `window.__realm`.

Comment: how does that work? How do I set the `__realm` to `process.env.REALM` ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood, using output will define your entire bundled module on the window object.  Many libraries use this functionality to create a global object that can be accessed anywhere when the module is imported.  If you just want to store a single string you can check out Andrey's answer.  DefinePlugin constants aren't accessed through the window object but the functionality is the same. Otherwise you could manually define it in, say, your index.js or other entry file: ```window.__realm = process.env.REALM```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey answer is the closest answer I've found anywhere, but not quite there.

This is what finally worked for me:

**In your Webpack config:**

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.FOO': JSON.stringify(true)})
```

**Somewhere in the top level of one of your project's source files:**

```js
window.FOO = process.env.FOO; // The necessity to do this seriously limits the utility of webpack.DefinePlugin in my view, but what can you do?
```

Even though `process` & `process.env` may be `undefined` when you try to access them, the value will be assigned to `window.FOO` successfully.

```js
console.log(window.FOO) // outputs: true
```